# 'It makes no sense trying sth' Would this be correct, too?

Tags: gerund-clauses

Can I say 'It makes no sense trying sth'? Actually it should be 'There is no sense/point/use (in) trying sth., I think.

Comment: Both are fine grammatically and idiomatically. However, philosophically and logically (in terms of problem-solving), they are kind of discouraging statements to make :) :D. Just an aside :).

Answer (score 1):

"It makes no sense trying X" = "It makes no sense to try X" = "There is no sense in trying X."

All will be understood (and understood in the same way) by native speakers of American English. All are idiomatic.

Answer (score -1):

I think this would make more sense-- "It makes no sense trying to do sth."

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.